# make an image to be center of the page when the page size is changed using bootstrap4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I need to add the thumbnail before the video using Jquery. I have added the image but when I change the page size the thumbnail is should be centered of the place As per the below image,
[image]

But, My image is responsive as below,
[image]

My Jquery,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("body").prepend('<div id="thumbnailcontainer" class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><img id="llthumbnail" class="img-fluid" style = "position: fixed;width: 100%;height: 100%;top: 0;left: 0; right: 0;bottom: 0;cursor: pointer;background:black;padding:0px 100px 0px 100px;" src = "http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10" ></div></div>');

    $('#thumbnailPlayIcon').on("click", function () {
     thumbnailClick($(this));
    });

    $('#llthumbnail').on("click", function () {
     thumbnailClick($(this));
    });

  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body> 
  <div id="myDiv">
  </div>
  <div class="skycap-caption" style="display:none"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

can any one please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide a fiddle where we can see the problem, instead of images. Probably the issue is in `style = "position: fixed;width: 100%;height: 100%;`, so it is always fixed to the same position and has same size. You probably have to position it inside a container that is being resized with page.

Comment: @Cray I added the code snippet

Comment: Since i'm not 100% sure what your expected result is, try removing `position: relative;` from the image style. That way the image is responsive and stays within the `thumbnailcontainer` element and resizes with it.

Comment: No, The image should be page responsive actually. The image should be centered when the page size is varied. (not to the top) @Cray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To position the image container in the middle of the page use following style (note that you need to remove `position: fixed;` from image).

```
#thumbnailcontainer {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

In the snippet (view in full screen) I added a `<div style="height:100vh;">`to emulate a larger page, which you should probably remove for your own page. Also you should keep the styles in a css file and HTML in html file, since it is hard to maintain a big blob in javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("body").prepend('<div style="height:100vh;"><div id="thumbnailcontainer" class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><img id="llthumbnail" class="img-fluid" style = "width: 100%;height: 100%;top: 0;left: 0; right: 0;bottom: 0;cursor: pointer;background:black;padding:0px 100px 0px 100px;" src = "http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10" ></div></div></div>');

    $('#thumbnailPlayIcon').on("click", function () {
     thumbnailClick($(this));
    });

    $('#llthumbnail').on("click", function () {
     thumbnailClick($(this));
    });

  });
```

```css
#thumbnailcontainer {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body> 
  <div id="myDiv">
  </div>
  <div class="skycap-caption" style="display:none"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The image should be in the center while the page size is reduced not in the top

Comment: It is in the center.